# is there a bug in java new String

Tags: java, concatenation

I try this code:

```
byte[] data = new byte[66000];
int count = is.read(data);
String sRequest = new String(data);  //will received byte array hello
String all = sRequest;        
all = all.concat("world");
System.out.println(all);
```

It only print to my console: **hello**

**concat** funtion of java have bug? I also used + operator instead concat function but result same :(
How can I concat a String with new String from a byte array?

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code you are testing? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: One thing you should note is that the result string has a length of 66005 since it includes all the null values from the array between `hello` and `world`.

Comment: me too. may be give us some part of your code aboe this line ...

Comment: You are ignoring the number of bytes returned. Note: not all characters are printable so you can't always expect to see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
    String sRequest = new String(data);  //will received byte array hello
```

use

```
    String sRequest = new String(data, 0, count);  //will received byte array hello
```

You will notice the difference when you additionally print the length of the result string:

```
    System.err.println(all + "/" + all.length());
```

gives `helloworld/66005` in the first case and `helloworld/10` in the second case. The reason you only see "hello" might be an issue of your console - in Eclipse, I do see "helloworld" but when I copy&paste that into another editor only one of the words is taken. The `0` values from the initial array are part of the result (since they already had been added to the first string), but they are not printed out (since they are not printable characters).

Comment: Great, it work perfect